# Create a custom page URL

Tags: php, pages, archive-template

I have and `archives.php` file developed which I want the user to be able to access. How can I register a new page so that when a user types `mysite.com/archives` he goes to this page?

Comment: Make this page template. Publish a new page with slug 'archives' and page template of this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make `archive.php` template .

And read this: [Category Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates)

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). Please add a solution and **explain** it.

Comment: I know , but this is all solution . He must making that file .

Answer (score 0):

Archive template is a category and taxonomy template, not for pages, but if you really want to do that, you can do it by:

1. Install "Page Links To" plugin
2. Create custom page template for this page by creating `page-archive.php` file